# les deux mots « gourd » et « engourdi » : quelles sont les différences de sens ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Quelles sont les différences entre ces deux mots « gourd » et « engourdi » ? Les deux mots sont-ils encore courants ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Engourdi » dénote le résultat d'une contrainte physique sur une partie du corps, le froid, l'immobilité prolongée, la pression anormale, etc., ce résultat étant une  sensation dans la partie donnée d'une perte importante de la souplesse habituelle de cette partie, de sa force, de son pouvoir de communiquer par le toucher des informations précises comme par exemple la rugosité des matériaux et leur température. C'est une forme d'incapacité passagère; on applique le terme aux jambes aux bras, aux mains et aux doigts mais aussi à d'autres parties, comme par exemple les lèvres ou les joues, ces dernières étant rendues souvent sujettes à un tel état (engourdissement) sous l'influence des anesthésiques qu'administrent les dentistes.

« Gourd » est un adjectif qui décrit figurativement une qualité des gestes et attitudes ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gourd)).

*B. − Au fig. Maladroit, gauche. Gestes, mouvements gourds. Dans sa chemise blanche qui le serrait aux poignets et au cou, il paraissait un peu empêtré, un peu gourd, et surtout ému et comme gêné (Roy, Bonheur occas.,1945, p. 425) :
2. De quelle sottise, le plus souvent, le blanc fait preuve, quand il s'indigne de la stupidité des noirs! Je ne les crois pourtant capables que d'un très petit développement, le cerveau gourd et stagnant le plus souvent dans une nuit épaisse... Gide, Voy. Congo,1927, p. 765.*

Cependant, cet adjectif est aussi applicable littéralement, comme le montre cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=19&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&content=doigts+gourds&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoigts%20gourds%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdoigts%20gourds%3B%2Cc0). Appliqué ainsi, au doigts, il signifie l'existence d'un engourdissement bénin qui peut être soit congénital soit passager et souvent sans cause apparente. On dit « avoir les doigts gourds ». Cette affliction est caractérisée par une inaptitude à manipuler les objets de façon parfaitement adroite et lorsque non congénitale  par la sensation d'un manque de souplesse dans les articulations.

Answer (score 5):

Est "engourdi" ce qui a été rendu "gourd", comme est "arrondi" ce qui a été rendu "rond" ou "alourdi" ce qui a été rendu "lourd". Si vous utilisez "engourdi", on s'attend quand même un peu à une cause :

> j'ai les doigts engourdis par le froid

mais ce n'est pas une obligation. Vous pouvez juste remarquer que vous avez les doigts engourdis sans savoir trop pourquoi.
Alors que si vous utilisez "gourd", c'est un constat:

> j'ai les doigts gourds.

Le terme "engourdi" est encore fréquent dans des phrases comme "j'ai le bras tout engourdi" par exemple. Le terme "gourd" l'est nettement moins, voire pas du tout.